# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

The error i'm getting is:
(SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.post_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`post_id` = 1 and `users`.`post_id` is not null).

I'm trying to consult a page of a post that contains two buttoms of Like and Dislike:

----> migration of the table likes:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('likes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->integer('post_id');
        $table->boolean('like');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

----> migration of the table users is:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();

    });
}
```

-------------------->My User model is :

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;

public function likes() {

return $this->hasMany(User::class);
}
/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];
 }
```

--------------> My Post model is:

```
 class Post extends Model
 {
public $table="posts";


 public function comments() {

return $this->hasMany(Comment::class)->orderBy('created_at');
}

 public function likes() {

return $this->hasMany(User::class);
 }
 }
```

-----------> My Like model is :

```
 class Like extends Model
  {
 public function post() {

return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
  }

 public function user() {

return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
 }
```

-------------and my Comment model is :

```
 class Comment extends Model
 {

 protected $fillable = [
'username', 'body', 'post_id'
 ];
public function post() {

return $this->belongsTo(Post::Class);
 }

  }
```

----> The part of code i'm calling out for variables in the blade Post.blade.php is :

```
  @php

        $like_count  = 0;
        $dislike_count = 0;

        @endphp

        @foreach ($post->likes as $like)
  @php

  if($like->like == 1)
 {
  $like_count++;

  }
  if($like->like == 0)
  {
   $dislike_count++;
 }

     @endphp
     @endforeach
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Like <i class="fa fa- 
        thumbs-up"></i><b> {{ $like_count }} </b>
        </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Dislike <i class="fa fa- 
       thumbs-down"></i> <b> {{ $dislike_count }} </b>
     </button>
```

I inserted some random numbers into the table likes manually according to user.id and post.id and i turned like=1

Comment: What function or which line is triggering that error? Your users table has no `post_id` column so it's causing the SQL Error. I think a relation is not set properly.

Comment: Hello,do you think i should add a new column with the name post_id as a foreign key in the table of users to solve this problem??

Comment: your relationship is messed up, the likes method of your Post model should return $this->hasMany(Like::class, 'id', 'post_id') and make sure your likes table has a post_id column

Comment: Hi @KhanShahrukh  thank you for your help, the error is gone but the buttoms don't seem to increment whenever i press on any of them, no fucntion seems to work, nothing happens, any suggestion?

Comment: look at the result in your controller by returning the $post collection before returning the view, most probably you will see a json object as a result and can judge whats happening

Comment: Hi @KhanShahrukh I forgot to mention that the likes were inserted into database manually just to see if it works my code above shows you what i really did, my intention was to see if it works or not and i picked a random user with its id and a random post with its id to insert into the databse table likes, as i said before the error is gone by the command you told me to add in my Post model but it still doesn't recuperate any data from my table likes, like and dislike buttoms are both set null always, any ideas???

Answer (score 0):

**Please change the post model relation hasMany to belongsTo**

return $this->hasMany(User::class);

replace with below code, it's works fine.

> return $this->belongsTo(User::class);